# Mimic an HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse object in Java

Tags: java, servlets

How do I mimic an `HTTPServletRequest` and `HTTPServletResponse` object. The reason is I want to test the behaviour of some servlets.

I know JUnit probably provides this functionality but I don't know how to use it (I will learn soon) and need to do this reasonably quickly.

HTTPServletRequest and HTTPServletResponse are both interfaces so they can't be instantiated. There is a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which implements HttpServletRequest but it doesn't seem to have any `setParameter()` type methods and HttpServletResponse doesn't seem to have any implementing classes at all.

How can I test my code by passing a suitable `HttpServletRequest` object and then checking that the received `HttpServletResponse` object matches what I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it's an interface makes it easier to mimic:  It's mocking final classes that's tricky.

```
class MyHttpServletRequest implements HttpServletRequest
{
  //whatever
}

class MyHttpServletResponse implements HttpServletResponse
{
  //whatever
}


doGet(new MyHttpServletRequest(),
      new MyHttpServletResponse())
```

Subclassing HttpServletRequestWrapper may be easier, but it's not necessary.   I would look at overriding [getParameter](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) and [getParameterMap](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html#getParameterMap%28%29)

Comment: Ok thanks ... that also gives me a better understanding of the point of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy object:

```
class MyDummyRequest implements HTTPServletRequest{
    //implement your own methods, for example:
    public Map getParameterMap(){
        Map myMap = new HashMap();
        //put the params you need inside myMap
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid creating dummy objects for test purposes you may look into one of the available [mocking](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) libraries for Java, such as Mockito.